# Implementing a different method for different types of arguments

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

I am writing some code to detect collision between different shapes, `RectShape`,`CircShape`,`LineShape` all inheriting from a base class `Shape`. My current implementation works really badly. First, I defined a bunch of case-specific functions:

```
bool LineLineCollision(LineShape& line1, LineShape& line2) {
    // do some math
}

bool CircRectCollision(CircShape& circ, RectShape& rect) {
    // some more math
}

// and so on for all cases
```

obviously all of these are required in any implementation. The issue is in the function `bool TestCollision(Shape& shp1, Shape& shp2)` which takes the two parameters, then goes through *many* if statements to compare `typeid(shp1)` and `typeid(shp2)` to the `typeid` of all my derived classes. It's dirty and messy but I didn't have any other ideas at the time. Now I'd like to clean it up. Adding a new type of shape is unimaginably annoying and time consuming.

My new idea right now is simply overloading `TestCollision` with arguments fitting different parameter types, but then I'll have to have `TestCollision(CircShape&, RectShape&)` and `TestCollision(RectShape&, CircShape&)` as two separate overloads and that's not maintainable. Another idea is to implement the functions inside the derived classes themselves, but it still results in duplication of code and is even less maintainable.

How would I tackle this issue?

Comment: It's a good time for learning the template metaprogramming in C++ using some of good C++ books.

Comment: @S.M. I had template specialization in mind, but it has two issues.The first one is how the parameters are ordered. Is it possible to take two parameter types in any order? The other thing is how I have to tell the function which types the arguments are, and that seems pointless, the compiler will be able to deduce that (I think this has to do with how `Shape` is a pure abstract class)

Comment: *Is it possible to take two parameter types in any order?* Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A*** solution would be to use a callback. e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Line;
struct Circ;

struct Shape {
    virtual void Collision(Line*) = 0;
    virtual void Collision(Circ*) = 0;
    virtual void Collision(Shape*) = 0;
};

class Line : public Shape {
private:
    void Collision(Line*) override {
        std::cout << "Line-Line\n";
    }
    void Collision(Circ*) override {
        std::cout << "Circ-Line\n";
    }
public:
    void Collision(Shape* other) override {
        other->Collision(this);
    }
};

class Circ : public Shape {
private:
    void Collision(Line*) override {
        std::cout << "Line-Circ\n";
    }
    void Collision(Circ*) override {
        std::cout << "Circ-Circ\n";
    }
public:
    void Collision(Shape* other) override {
        other->Collision(this);
    }
};

#include<memory>

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> obj1 = std::make_unique<Line>();
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> obj2 = std::make_unique<Circ>();
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> obj3 = std::make_unique<Line>();

    obj1->Collision(obj2.get());
    obj1->Collision(obj3.get());

}
```

outputs:

```
Line-Circ
Line-Line
```